# SQL Connection String Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, database-connection

I have been trying to get my program to connect to my database for the last 4 hours but I can not get it to work. I am writing a WPF desktop application which needs to connect to a database to save user created content. I have the database created and can view it in SQL Management Studio but I cannot get my connection string to work.

I have looked at all other questions related to this but cannot find a solution. When I step through my code an exception occurs when the connection to the database attempts to open.

Exception: `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

Here is my code:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=./SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=PrinterEmulator;Integrated Security=True;";

MySqlConnection conn;

try
{
    using (conn = new MySqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        conn.Open();  //Exception occurs here

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [PrinterEmulator].[dbo].[LEDM](NamesOfTablesHere) VALUES(ValuesToBeInsertedHere)", conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Also I am using SQLExpress.

This has been wrecking my head for the last few hours so any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **SqlServer** as database, but you are using classes that are used for interacting with **MySQL** , you should be using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` which are for SqlServer

Comment: Oh right I didn't even realise there was a difference, I think I need to go back to the drawing board so thanks!

Comment: It's finding the db now but I have a new exception, here we go again :P Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It is there's a permission problem on the db now, I'll have to grant the permissions properly. Thanks.